# Boot with "noacpi" automatically from hard drive?

Tags: kernel, support, grub2, acpi

If I boot ubuntu from the live cd without any special options I get the following message:

> [    0.040001] Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work! Boot with apic=debug and send a report.  Then try booting with the 'noapic' option.
>   [    0.040001]

So I booted with the noapic option (and the acpi=off option because the noapic option alone didn't work). It booted fine and I was able to install. Then after the restart I got the above message again. Is there a way to tell ubuntu to use the noapic option when booting from harddrive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using GRUB2 (clean-installs of Ubuntu 9.04 and later), edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the following line: (this may look different on your system, I just took it from mine as an example)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Add `noacpi`, or whichever kernel option you want, anywhere in the line.

If you're using GRUB Legacy (if you upgraded from a version of Ubuntu before 9.10), please [see the GRUB page in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto#Modifying%20boot%20options%20in%20GRUB) for details on how to edit your `/boot/grub/menu.list` to accomplish the same as above.

Comment: I couldn't execute grub-update from the live cd so I mounted my ubuntu partition and added acpi=off noapic to the kernel line in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

that worked, thanks!

Comment: @user142 Make sure you keep those updates in /etc/default/grub - the grub.cfg gets rebuilt every time there is an update to grub (new kernel, etc)

Comment: just had this issue with an older laptop again and it worked yippee!

Answer (score 1):

To do this you must change the boot parameters through Grub. Open /etc/default/grub as root. Add noapic to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" or similar. Then run update-grub as root.

Comment: I guess I started writing this as lfaraone posted his answer