# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, pulseaudio, 20.04, xdg

> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR  is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999!(This could eg happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)`

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.4 as Dual Boot with Windows 10 on my Dell G3 gaming PC.

After hitting 'Install Now', the system hangs at 'searching filesystems' at the error message in bold shown at the beginning of this post - about the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR.

In another Ubuntu forum question, the suggested fix was switching off 'fast startup' in Power Options>Control Panel in Windows 10. Did that, but no help at all.

Guys please help me out.
Thanks in advance:).

Comment: I figured it out, guys. This is for those of you who didn't. While booting the live USB/CD, toggle to 'Try Ubuntu' and press <e> to edit the install command line. Append 'acpi=off' to 'quiet splash' and press F10. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot with "noacpi" automatically from hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3431/boot-with-noacpi-automatically-from-hard-drive)

Comment: Is your BIOS configured to use **secure boot** and did you choose to install 3rd party drivers? The installer for version 21.10 allow to tick this option without enforcing to provide a secure boot password. Looked like it was my problem

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the similar problem. The installation seemed to be stuck on unpacking some lib and kept showing:

`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999!(This could eg happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)`

Had to wait on it for about 20-25 minutes, then the warning message changed and the installation continued.
I would say if the installation is not aborting, then try and wait this error out.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

When booting from USB Press "try Ubuntu"
Open a terminal window

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the following line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset noacpi"

Close the terminal window and press the install Ubuntu on the desktop

Comment: unfortunately this does not work anymore with the new version