# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us

Tags: dual-boot

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999!(This could eg happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
[here was an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241795/xdg-runtime-dir-is-not-owned-by-us-uid-0) but unfortunately it’s too late to try and run the trial version.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.4 as Dual Boot with Windows 10 on my HP Omen 15.
I did the disk partitioning myself and now I’m stuck on the install screen while it says ‘Running Dpkg’. The skip button doesn’t work as well because the mouse button is showing a loading symbol.

Some solutions are saying to change acpi to off and change nomodeset, how exactly do I go about that from the install screen?

Can giving a lot of space to swap give this error?

Is it possible I restart this install without bricking my storage?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.