# Issues installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 as only OS on Acer Nitro 5

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, 20.04, acer

My installation process is stuck at `Almost finished copying files`.

To get there, I mostly followed https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/903305/#Comment_903305:

- on my Dell, `dd`-ed the ubuntu 20.04 iso from the official website into a 32GB usb stick
- on the Acer, disabled secure boot, switch SATA mode to AHCI, enabled F12BootMenu, disabled Fast Boot, saved and rebooted, entered the GRUB menu.

In the grub menu, I tried both normal installation, and safe graphics installation, but both seem to lead to the same results.

I also tried adding `nomodeset` to the GRUB lines and pressing `C-x` to boot through them. They were different from what I saw online because of the `---` at the end:

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash ---
```

I tried adding  `nomodeset` after `splash`, and after `---` on another reboot, but no change there.

I also tried `noacpi` by changing the grub file on the live trial, as explained in [XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241795/xdg-runtime-dir-is-not-owned-by-us-uid-0), but no change.

Not connecting to wifi, selecting a minimal installation, and not installing third party software seemed to have no effect either.

They all lead to getting stuck at `Almost finished copying files`, with a log similar to this, from `cat /var/log/syslog`: https://pastebin.com/xHdncmHK

I can share command output after setting up a local js server on my Dell to put `post` data into a file and running `wget -qO- 192.168.0.157:8000 --post-file=<file>`.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5009 (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 2600 (rev 21)
```

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0     2G  0 loop /rofs
loop1         7:1    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop2         7:2    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop3         7:3    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop4         7:4    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop5         7:5    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
sda           8:0    1  28.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1   512M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    1  28.4G  0 part /target
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /target/boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 952.8G  0 part /cdrom
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0     1G  0 part
```

This one is a bit puzzling because I didn't select `zfs` as my filesystem

```
$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio-enable-autospawn
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
 [ - ]  zfs-import
 [ + ]  zfs-mount
 [ + ]  zfs-share
 [ + ]  zfs-zed
```

In fact, I'm not even sure where my main partition ended up, it's supposed to be a 1TB SSD:

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 fuseblk   953G   48G  906G   6% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   7.8G   81M  7.7G   2% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   60K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/loop1     squashfs   30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop2     squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop3     squashfs  256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop4     squashfs   63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop5     squashfs   50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/sda2      ext4       28G  5.5G   21G  21% /target
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat       96M   52M   45M  54% /target/boot/efi
```

Comment: I've kind of fixed this by installing the nvidia version of Pop!_OS. Installation worked out of the box (the bios is still in the state I left it by trying to install ubuntu)